# Excel addin development environment

Tags: c++, excel, add-in

If I want to build an excel addin with C++. Is there any opensource/freeware alternative to the Visual Studio development environment?

Thanks

Dean

Answer (score 2):

For interfacing with excel you can use should check out [XLW](http://xlw.sourceforge.net/refman/main.html). I'm not sure on it's current state of development or if it is updated for the current version of excel. With excel 12 they added some features for larger data sets, more rows and columns and a multi-threaded calculation engine.

As far as compiling the code you can use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). You can also download the [express editions of Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/) if it is for yourself. If you are working commercially, just get Visual Studio. It's that good.

Answer (score 2):

Free? How about [Microsoft Visual C++ Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/)?

The former [Borland C++ Builder compiler](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Free.aspx?id=24778) also appears to be freely downloadable. Not sure about version, though, and you'd need some way to edit/debug.

Then there's something available in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php)

There are plenty more. See [this list](http://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/cpp.shtml)

Don't forget the [Excel SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687827.aspx) and make sure you're aware of the [changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2007/12/09/building-an-excel-xll-in-c-c-with-vs-2008.aspx) that appeared in Excel 2007...

Comment: hey not a huge deal, but when i see a link, i expect a url and not a huge zip file.  i'm talking about the eclipse link.  next time, i think you should link to a webpage that offers the download instead.